# jQuery .each() not iterating over array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array with an array length of 2. However when I try to use the jQUery .each function to iterate through the array I am only seeing the first element in the array console logging out.

This is how my array looks like :

```
0:{location_name: "none", mid: "none", lat: "", lng: ""}
1:{location_name: "1 Helena St, Burnley BB10 4AP, UK", mid: 0, lat: "53.78812", lng: "-2.231830"}
```

However when I try to loop :

```
$.each(customerChosenMarkers, function(index, tag) {
        console.log("LOOP ", index);
});
```

This console log only gives me 0 when printing out index. I was expecting 0 and 1. I have tried adding more things to the array but still one less.

Further Code:

```
function mapUpdateLocation(event, mid, type) {

    var locationName = getAddress(event.position.lat().toFixed(5), event.position.lng().toFixed(6));
    deepAll(locationName).then(function(values) {
        if (type == "add") {
            customerChosenMarkers.push({
                "location_name" : values.formatted_address,
                "mid" : mid,
                "lat" : event.position.lat().toFixed(5),
                "lng" : event.position.lng().toFixed(6)
            });
        }

        if (type == "edit") {
            var length = customerChosenMarkers.length;
            customerChosenMarkers[length-1] = {
                "location_name" : values.formatted_address,
                "lat" : event.position.lat().toFixed(5),
                "lng" : event.position.lng().toFixed(6)
            };
        }

    });


    console.log(customerChosenMarkers);

    $.each(customerChosenMarkers, function(index, tag) {
        console.log("LOOP ", index);
    });


}
```

Comment: Nope, that's not true. You have something else wrong - `var arr = Array.from({
0:{location_name: "none", mid: "none", lat: "", lng: ""},
1:{location_name: "1 Helena St, Burnley BB10 4AP, UK", mid: 0, lat: "53.78812", lng: "-2.231830"},
length: 2});
$.each(arr, (i, tag) => console.log(i, tag)); // logs both`

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Hi @BenjaminGruenbaum sorry I didn't understand what you meant there ?

Comment: @dark_illusion_909099 I mean that I ran your code, and it does not output what you claim it does. The above code posted is proof of the incorrect behavior report

Comment: @dark_illusion_909099 is your array **really** an array, or is it a plain object?

Comment: "This is how my array looks like" That's not what an array looks like.

Comment: @dark_illusion_909099 - Benjamin wrote example code to show `$.each` is working as expected. Ele asked you to post a complete example - currently we can't see what you array looks like. We cannot reporuce your problem unless you include code like `var customerChosenMarkers = [{...},{...}]`

Comment: Sorry it's not an array, it's an object

Comment: I have updated my question, I am adding elements into the object as an when I call this function

Comment: Async problem detected!

Comment: I have looked into async, can you suggest a way around it ?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the snippet example

```js
var customerChosenMarkers=    [
    
    {location_name: "none", mid: "none", lat: "", lng: ""},
    {location_name: "1 Helena St, Burnley BB10 4AP, UK", mid: 0, lat: "53.78812", lng: "-2.231830"}
    
    ]
    
    $.each(customerChosenMarkers, function(index, tag) {
        console.log("LOOP ", index);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```